# Juju local shared folder

Tags: juju, shared-folders, lxc

I'm using juju local and I want to create a shared folder between the host and one of the juju machines.

How can I accomplish this?

I attempted these instructions with no success : [https://en.opensuse.org/User:Tsu2/LXC_mount_shared_directory](https://en.opensuse.org/User%3aTsu2/LXC_mount_shared_directory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no official juju ways of doing it, but the machines are just lxc containers.

You can stop the container and edit the config file for that container (found in /var/lib/lxc) and add a line to mount the folder.

The restart the container and the directory will be mounted.

Comment: Great, my problem was I was modifying the config file under /etc/lxc. Additionally, I will point out to anyone that the config files are auto generated so by modifying the template config file (/var/lib/lxc/{ubuntu-version}-template/{configFileNamw}) the change will not be carried over.

Answer (score 0):

From the host, if you have ssh set up correctly, you can

```
sshfs <username>@<containerMachine> 'mkdir /container/directory/to/mount/host/dir ; sshfs -o idmap=user <username>@<hostMachine>:/host/dir/to/share /container/directory/to/mount/host/dir ; '
```

This is a temporary mount that will disappear at next reboot.